# Login with Windows 8 store apps in LOB cases

Tags: authentication, windows-8, windows-runtime, restful-authentication, windows-store-apps

Given I have an existing user store as database and are not allowed to use google, facebook, twitter, etc logins in a business scenario. What would be the best practise to do authentication against a backend server?

As backend I plan to server Json via web api. Since Web api implements oauth2 and Windows store apps do also. Is there an easy way to leverage the oauth2 protocol with for example asp.net membership (or different user store). I know this is a totally different concept but I was looking for a solution to use build in infrastruktur... without to have or install an identity server.
Since the Windows Store App are not a browser, so how do the token back and forth dance work with the back end...

So these are just my thought ... How would be story for authentication for Windows 8 store apps in LOB cases?

Any pointers, links, thoughts would be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker) class to present a web-view (browser view) and do all the things required for oauth in client side. One important note: you have to call this broker's authenticate method in the main/UI thread! There's even a Facebook example at the link. For server/backend: I'm not familiar with asp.net based backends, we use Ruby on Rails with oauth gem.